# Is of generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a hierarchy interface of IRoot where H is the hierarchy type and N is the node type. I want to work out if an object is of type IRoot, how would I do this...

I have looked as types matching, reflection interfaces and isassignedfrom, all don't work

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far?  It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: There is an `IRoot<H, N>` and you want to see if an object implements this regardless of what the choices for `H` and `N` are?

Comment: if (obj.GetType() is typeof(IRoot<H,N>))
   {
    'do something
   }

Comment: @PhilWhittaker This won't work.

Comment: @FelixK. he knows, which is why he's asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
var ifc = obj.GetType().GetInterface(typeof(IRoot<,>).Name);
if(ifc != null) {
    // operate assuming type is IRoot<,>
}
```

Make sure to read the documentation on `GetInterface()` and open generic types. This is weird stuff, so it's important to understand what's going on here.

EDIT: you can also use `typeof(IRoot<,>).Name` in place of `` "IRoot`2" `` in order to avoid having to use hard-coded strings. I've updated the above code to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the siride's answer:

If you can change the definition of `IRoot<H, N>` so that it is `IRoot<H,N> : IRoot`, then the following will also work:

```
object someInstance = new SomeDerivedClass<TFoo, TBar>();
bool isOfRoot = typeof (IRoot).IsInstanceOfType(someInstance);
```

or even

```
bool isOfRoot = someInstance is IRoot;
```

This makes it a bit more type safe as no strings are involved.

Comment: You can sidestep the string problem by just using `typeof(IRoot<,>).Name` instead of hardcoding it. I'll update my answer.